# What does for(int i=0,u,v; ...) mean?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I was looking through some C++ code and I saw that the for loop was `for(int i=0,u,v;i<M;++i)`. I understand most of the for-loop but I didn't understand the `int i = 0, u, v`. My question is: is this just a way of initialing u and v? What is the purpose of putting them there? I'm new to cpp so I'm not sure what this means. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, `u` and `v` are uninitialised.  They are *declared*, and exist for the duration of the `for` loop, as does `i`.  They have type `int`.

That said, I would not write code this way as I find it unnecessarily obscure.  I would write (adding some spaces for legibility):

```
for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
{
    int u, v;
    ...
}
```

Although, as pointed out in the comments, the lifetime of `u` and `v` is not strictly equivalent;

Comment: `u` and `v` have a different lifetime here. The equivalent code would be `{ int u, v; for(...) { ... } }`.

Comment: Ah okay, got it. I actually didn't write this code so I was wondering why they did it this way as opposed to your way. Thank you

Comment: @Quentin Are you sure?  See: https://wandbox.org/permlink/NcEMcyN46hiphFgY (or indeed https://wandbox.org/permlink/Et9FBiiLfk5ng5vh).

Comment: @PaulSanders Consider what happens in both cases if the body of the loop is `if (i == 0) { u = 10; } else { std::cout << u; }`. I may be wrong, but I believe the OP's and Quentin's code would be well-defined for that body, whereas yours would exhibit UB.

Comment: @Brian Ah, I see what you mean. Point taken, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`int i=0,u,v;` declares three variables of type int: i, u, v. i is initialized to 0 and u and v are uninitialized, meaning you have to write some value to them before you are allowed to read from them. Their scope is limited to the for-loop block.

Comment: `extern int i = 0, u, v;` **declares** three variables. `int i = 0, u, v;` **defines** three variables. The first says “these three variables exist somewhere”. The second says “here they are”.